# Matlab live script does not output the same as regular script

Tags: matlab

This script run as live script does not run the same as running as normal script. It runs as expected as normal script, but with live script it seems that the outputs lag behind by one run. Would there be a script fix to run this as wanted as a .mlx type?

The Live Script's whitespace seems to be a bit off, but otherwise both run the same. The 'bit off' part is not wanted.

```
clear
clc
orig='Jmkyvih$mx$syx$}ixC';
fprintf('original input is ''Jmkyvih$mx$syx$}ixC''\n')
yn=0;
counter=0;
while yn==0
    yn= input('enter ''1'' to end the process or ''0'' to continue the loop\n');

    if yn==1
        fprintf('conversion found, %.0f loops were run to make the text readable\n',counter)
        fprintf('string run %1.0f is "%s" \n\n',counter,orig)
        break;
    elseif  yn~=0
        error('restart and input a valid number')
    else
    end
    fprintf('conversion not found\n ')
    counter=counter+1;
    orig=char(double (orig)-1);
    fprintf('string run %1.0f is "%s" \n\n',counter,orig)
end
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this after entering three `0`s and a `1` in both environments.  The only difference appears to be that the Live Script doesn't output `input` prompts.  I got the same textual output between the traditional and Live Script mechanisms after I deleted all user input from the traditional method.  That said, the Live Script's whitespace seems to be a bit off, but it runs the same for me.

Comment: Yeah, what I meant is that the white live space is off.